# allocation memory in C int *p = malloc(n * sizeof(int)); vs int *p = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to learn what is the difference between:

1. `int *p = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));` AND
2. `int *p = (int*)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));`

when initializing a dynamic array in C, and I can't get it, any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `int *p = malloc(3 * sizeof *p);` for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

In C there's no need for such operation, which is called *[cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)*, because a `void*` pointer is implicitly convertible to any kind of pointer.

In C++ you would require it because there's no such implicit conversion, but you will be using `new` instead that `malloc`, which wouldn't require it at all.